# Non-static variable of cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, static, non-static

I'm trying to call my `createFile` method from the `OpenFile` class in my main method, but I keep getting the error saying that I cannot call a non-static variable from a static context.

I did try calling `OpenFile of = new OpenFile();` inside my main method, but that didn't work so I'm currently declaring `OpenFile` above my main method which works fine, however every time I try to use one of `OpenFile`s methods I get the same error.

I've tried prefacing a few things with `static` but that just causes my IDE to show an Erroneous sym type error, which I think is caused by whatever is causing the other error.

Here is `createFile` from `OpenFile`:

```
public class OpenFile {

    private Formatter file;

    public void createFile() throws FileNotFoundException{

        try{
            file = new Formatter("test.txt");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error creating file.");
    }
    }
```

and here is my main method:

```
OpenFile of = new OpenFile();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    of.createFile();
    intro();
    createAndShowRibbon();
    createAndShowNormalUI();

}
```

Is it something to do with Formatter? I've never used it before.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6730716/2864740 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/4308942/2864740 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/7638196/2864740

Comment: Please search first. It has nothing to do with the `Formatter` type.

Comment: Too fundamental question, need to explore first i feel too :(.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
OpenFile of = new OpenFile();
```

should be

```
static OpenFile of = new OpenFile();
```

You're accessing it from your `static void main` method. If this variable is not declared `static`, it will not be available to the method when it is statically executed.

Comment: Seems to run! Although it runs when I add static to `OpenFile` but only when I also add `throws FileNotFoundException` to the main method, what's up with that?

Comment: @JoshJahans: you are calling `of.createFile();` which throws that very same exception. Since it's being thrown there instead of caught (using `try { } catch { }`), it has to be either thrown or caught in the next method, `main` in this example.

Comment: You can't call something that doesn't exist. Since you haven't created an object, the non-static method doesn't exist yet. A static method (by definition) always exists.

Answer (score 2):

Since **main method** in java is most popular method among all beginners and
they try to put program code there they face ***`"non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context"`*** compiler error when they  try to access a non static member **variable inside main in Java which is static**.

Please take a look at this article
**[Why non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context?](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/02/why-non-static-variable-cannot-be.html)**

---

In your case you have to make the `OpenFile of = new OpenFile();` instantiation to be static like as shown below in order to access that in main method which is a static method.

```
static OpenFile of = new OpenFile();  // should be static for accessing within main method
public static void main(String[] args) {

    of.createFile();
    intro();
    createAndShowRibbon();
    createAndShowNormalUI();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is non-static.

```
OpenFile of = new OpenFile();
```

But you're calling it from a main method, which is static.

Try changing to:

```
static OpenFile of = new OpenFile();
```

Answer (score 1):

in the static method u can call Class methods or variables which is static
but u can't call instance variables or method in